# Ubuntu 14.04 install stuck at Preparing to install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ubiquity

I am trying to install uUbuntu 14.04 in my Dell N5110 laptop.
While installing the installer gets stuck at **Preparing to install** screen.
When I checked **syslog** for errors the following came up:

```
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.686513] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.686522] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.686535] ata1.00: cmd 60/01:d0:4e:58:31/00:00:29:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq 512 in
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.686535]          res 41/40:01:4e:58:31/00:00:29:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.686541] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.686546] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746707] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746747] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746755] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746761] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746765] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746769] Read(10): 28 00 29 31 58 4e 00 00 01 00
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746788] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 691099726
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746798] Buffer I/O error on dev sda6, logical block 6293582, async page read
Sep 25 16:28:12 ubuntu kernel: [  237.746840] ata1: EH complete
Sep 25 16:28:14 ubuntu kernel: [  240.241475] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0xf SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Sep 25 16:28:14 ubuntu kernel: [  240.241495] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Sep 25 16:28:14 ubuntu kernel: [  240.241500] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

The laptop has Windows 7 preinstalled. What can I do to resolve this problem and install Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.10 Installation Hangs at 'Preparing to Install Ubuntu'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204771/ubuntu-12-10-installation-hangs-at-preparing-to-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Not a duplicate ; hardware issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurred because some partitions were having bad sectors. I've formatted them and then the installation worked fine.
Another work around is to mount the partitions with gnome disks and then the installer works fine.

Comment: How did you format it? Using `gparted`? Then which file system did you use, fat32 or ext4?

Answer (score 1):

What is odd is that this is a laptop certified for Ubuntu according to this site: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201012-6932/

However, note that it is certified specifically for an older version. At this point, I'd suggest giving that version a try (there's a link on the page) or, perhaps, giving a different Buntu a try - perhaps Lubuntu, but an Ubuntu without Unity. There's a few open bugs with that specific laptop but most of them had to do with power management (suspend/resume) from what I was able to see.

Anyhow, I was able to get a few hits just by using the laptop model number and Ubuntu as the search terms. I did not find anything specifically matching your problem, however.