# Ubuntu 14.04 Install Hangs at "Preparing to install Ubuntu"

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, ubiquity

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) alongside Windows 10 with a UEFI-capable motherboard (Asus Z87-Pro) onto a fresh SSD. However, my installation hangs at the stage of **Preparing to install Ubuntu**.

I have taken the following steps to get to this point:

1. Used Rufus to load the Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) ISO onto a USB flash drive
2. Disabled secureboot/fastboot on the BIOS
3. Boot with the "Try Ubuntu" option from GNU GRUB with the option **nomodeset**

I have been trying to use **System Log** in order to troubleshoot why the installation hangs. For reference, the layout of the drives is such:

- /dev/sda - Windows 10 SSD
- /dev/sdb - Windows 10 HDD
- /dev/sdc - Unformatted SSD to be used for Ubuntu
- /dev/sdd - USB flash drive containing Ubuntu

The following is the relevant printout from **System Log**.

```
Dec 13 01:51:43 ubuntu ubiquity[4098]: switched to page prepare
Dec 13 01:51:45 ubuntu ubiquity[4098]: debconffilter_done: ubi-prepare (current: ubi-prepare)
Dec 13 01:51:45 ubuntu ubiquity[4098]: Step_before = stepPrepare
Dec 13 01:51:45 ubuntu activate-dmraid: No Serial ATA RAID disks detected
Dec 13 01:51:45 ubuntu partman:   No matching physical volumes found
Dec 13 01:51:45 ubuntu partman:   Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Dec 13 01:51:45 ubuntu partman:   No volume groups found
Dec 13 01:51:45 ubuntu partman-lvm:   No volume groups found
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Device name        : /dev/sda4
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: NTFS volume version: 3.1
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current volume size: 118536270336 bytes (118537 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current device size: 118536273920 bytes (118537 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Checking filesystem consistency ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Accounting clusters ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Space in use       : 83905 MB (70.8%)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Collecting resizing constraints ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: You might resize at 83904434176 bytes or 83905 MB (freeing 34632 MB).
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Device name        : /dev/sda5
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: NTFS volume version: 3.1
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current volume size: 470807040 bytes (471 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current device size: 470810624 bytes (471 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Checking filesystem consistency ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Accounting clusters ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Space in use       : 351 MB (74.4%)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Collecting resizing constraints ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: You might resize at 350404608 bytes or 351 MB (freeing 120 MB).
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Device name        : /dev/sda6
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: NTFS volume version: 3.1
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current volume size: 471855616 bytes (472 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current device size: 471859200 bytes (472 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Checking filesystem consistency ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Accounting clusters ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Space in use       : 347 MB (73.4%)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Collecting resizing constraints ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: You might resize at 346177536 bytes or 347 MB (freeing 125 MB).
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Device name        : /dev/sdb1
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: NTFS volume version: 3.1
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current volume size: 314569216 bytes (315 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current device size: 314572800 bytes (315 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Checking filesystem consistency ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Accounting clusters ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Space in use       : 251 MB (79.7%)
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Collecting resizing constraints ...
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: You might resize at 250695680 bytes or 251 MB (freeing 64 MB).
Dec 13 01:51:50 ubuntu ntfsresize: Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Device name        : /dev/sdb4
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: NTFS volume version: 3.1
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current volume size: 894321029632 bytes (894322 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current device size: 894321033216 bytes (894322 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Checking filesystem consistency ...
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Accounting clusters ...
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Space in use       : 482198 MB (53.9%)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Collecting resizing constraints ...
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: You might resize at 482197037056 bytes or 482198 MB (freeing 412124 MB).
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Device name        : /dev/sdb5
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: NTFS volume version: 3.1
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current volume size: 471855616 bytes (472 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Current device size: 471859200 bytes (472 MB)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Checking filesystem consistency ...
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Accounting clusters ...
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Space in use       : 349 MB (73.9%)
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Collecting resizing constraints ...
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: You might resize at 348536832 bytes or 349 MB (freeing 123 MB).
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ntfsresize: Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.426236] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.426326] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.426400] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.426490] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda3
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.426601] FAT-fs (sda3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.426602] FAT-fs (sda3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.427283] XFS (sda3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: you must specify the filesystem type
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.493457] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.493612] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.493736] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.493915] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sdb3
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.494036] FAT-fs (sdb3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.494038] FAT-fs (sdb3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.494585] XFS (sdb3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.577154] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.577231] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.577361] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.577458] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda3
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.577531] FAT-fs (sda3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.577533] FAT-fs (sda3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:56 ubuntu kernel: [  649.578060] XFS (sda3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  649.598377] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  649.598485] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  649.598574] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  649.598697] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sdb3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  649.598792] FAT-fs (sdb3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  649.598793] FAT-fs (sdb3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  649.599236] XFS (sdb3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.010459] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.010540] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.010615] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.010679] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.010762] FAT-fs (sda3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.010763] FAT-fs (sda3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.011276] XFS (sda3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.054578] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.054678] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.054767] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.054855] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sdb3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.054942] FAT-fs (sdb3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.054943] FAT-fs (sdb3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.055466] XFS (sdb3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.163349] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.163421] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.163478] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.163536] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.163594] FAT-fs (sda3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.163595] FAT-fs (sda3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.164110] XFS (sda3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.184738] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.184857] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.184952] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.185075] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sdb3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.185170] FAT-fs (sdb3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.185171] FAT-fs (sdb3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.185628] XFS (sdb3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.420601] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.420700] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.420789] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.420866] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.420948] FAT-fs (sda3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.420950] FAT-fs (sda3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.421467] XFS (sda3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.442600] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.442708] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.442819] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.442920] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sdb3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.443013] FAT-fs (sdb3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.443015] FAT-fs (sdb3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.443537] XFS (sdb3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.528251] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.528326] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.528385] EXT4-fs (sda3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.528442] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sda3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.528500] FAT-fs (sda3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.528501] FAT-fs (sda3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.529042] XFS (sda3): Invalid superblock magic number
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.549763] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.549860] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.549953] EXT4-fs (sdb3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.550053] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on sdb3
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.550145] FAT-fs (sdb3): bogus number of reserved sectors
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.550146] FAT-fs (sdb3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Dec 13 01:51:57 ubuntu kernel: [  650.550634] XFS (sdb3): Invalid superblock magic number
```

I have looked at and have tried solutions from various other forum posts, including the following:

- [Ubuntu 12.10 Installation Hangs at 'Preparing to Install Ubuntu' [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204771/ubuntu-12-10-installation-hangs-at-preparing-to-install-ubuntu)
- [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Got freezing while preparing to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252292/ubuntu-12-04-lts-got-freezing-while-preparing-to-install)

I have tried different configurations of internet connectivity. I have also tried various approaches with the unformatted SSD, such as formatting it before installation or trying it without formatting it. I also tried the trick suggested from the first link of using

```
ps -ef | egrep "dosfsck|ntfs"
```

but to no avail. It does not seem to make a noticeable difference when choosing the boot option "Install Ubuntu" as opposed to "Try Ubuntu" either -- I've left both options running for long periods of time, and no progress *seems* to be made either time.

Any help with troubleshooting this issue (with what I hope are helpful logs) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure why I didn't think of this sooner, but I decided to try the installation after disconnecting my Windows-related disks (in this case, /dev/sda and /dev/sdb) by disconnecting both the power and the SATA cables. When I tried to run the installation again, it worked instantly and used the "Something Else" install option in Ubiquity to install it to the properly formatted 500GB SSD (with an EFI System Partition, swap partition, and ext4 partition).

I also ran sudo update-grub after reconnecting the Windows disks so that Grub could find the Windows bootloader.

I'm now in the process of fixing some post-install issues (seems like driver-related issues). Hope this proves useful to someone.